# How to open Dynamic custom tab from MS Teams chatbot section

Tags: node.js, botframework, chatbot, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards

need to open a **custom tab**  when button click from chat bot section
please guide me to create a dynamic tab creation from MS Teams chat bot section.
[please find the image for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbUql.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can Redirect from chat to tab using deeplink. You can create deep links to entities in Teams. This is used to create links that navigate to content and information within your tab. Please check this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/build-and-test/deep-links#deep-linking-to-your-tab).

Comment: But I want to open a dynamic Tab using MS Teams chat bot button click's ..then is it possible ???.

Comment: Tab should not open by default ..... is it possible using deep link ?

Comment: @sivasubramanian - you can deeplink to existing Tabs only.

Answer (score 0):

Try the MS Graph API to dynamically create tab.
The API should be like this in a conversation:
*/chats/{chat.id}/tabs*